# Prevent dijit.TooltipDialog from closing

Tags: javascript, dialog, dojo

How to prevent a dijit.TooltipDialog from closing? I want it to close only when the user clicks in certain button.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a widget as your content. Broadcast a button click event from there and register an event handler in the class where your TooltipDialog is. Use popup.open and close to manually handle your TooltipDialog.

```
// class WidgetWithButton
on(button, 'click', function(evt) {
    this.onButtonClick(evt);
});

// this is your class
var yourWidget = new WidgetWithButton();
var myTooltipDialog = new TooltipDialog({
    id: 'myTooltipDialog',
    content: yourWidget
});
on(yourWidget, 'buttonClick', function(evt) {
    popup.close(myTooltipDialog);
});
on(dom.byId('thenode'), 'mouseover', function() {
    popup.open({
        popup: myTooltipDialog,
        around: dom.byId('thenode')
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, got confused. I've just updated the answer :)

Comment: Thanks! But that is not the scenario, I should have been more specific, my bad. I'm running dojo 1.6 and I have a form within a dijit.TooltipDialog that is called programatically. One of those form elements calls a dijit.Dialog window when clicked on. The thing is that I want the TooltipDialog to remain opened while the user is using the Dialog. And as soon as I focus on a widget within the dialog, the TooltipDialog closes. Thanks anyway! Your solution could be useful for people using dojo > 1.7

Comment: Hey, I'm willing to upvote you just for your effort, but I'm not familiar yet with the policies at stackoverflow, and this, although a good one, is not the answer to my problem :/.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't get it. Why shouldn't it work for Dojo 1.6? My answer is based on [this example](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/TooltipDialog). The TooltipDialog is only closed onMouseLeave and nothing happens when you focus on the dialog. Btw, upvote is the up arrow next to my post :)

Comment: I just mentioned dojo 1.6 as an (extra) probably useful data, considering a potential change in the implementation. I just want to avoid the TooltipDialog from getting closed when the user clicks somewhere outside the dialog.

Comment: If you look at the example I gave you, it works just like you said. You just need to adjust the events and the respective handlers. If you're still stuck, post your code ;)